# Is it possible to develop AAA game engines in Java?(or in any language on the JVM)

Tags: java, optimization, jvm, game-engine

Or will it be possible in the near future? Can they optimize JVM further and implement even gentler garbage collectors, maybe with some support for lower-level interference?

I could have asked the question if it's possible to develop AAA games, but since AAA games use highly advanced game engines, I thought the barrier to overcome here is to have similarly advanced game engines written to the JVM.

Is it likely that in 5 years we will see games like Assassin's Creed, that are optimized to infinity with the help of C/C++ libraries by necessity, written in Java?

Comment: Please note thar your wuestion is likely to be closed as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Don't know much about games, but Minecraft has just been bought by Microsoft for 2 billion dollars, and it's written in Java.

Comment: define "AAA game" ... how is it different from an "AA game" or "A game" and how does that affect your question?

Answer (score 4):

For the most part, the intensive work is done on the GPU and these are getting more powerful all the time.

You can use the GPU from Java already and JavaFX does this as well as a number of CV libraries.

A simple way to get gentiler garbage pauses is to create less garbage. You program will run faster as well.

Another effective technique is to move the bulk of your data off heap. For minecraft server this can reduce the heap size by 80% and significantly reduce the frequency and pause time of collections.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/minecraft-and-off-heap-memory.html?m=1

Comment: So the answer is yes? Could you imagine the next Half-Life or Crysis written in Java then?

Comment: @RyanMarv not so much.  While it could be done this way, most developers in the field will be GPU/C/C++ developers and just because they could use another language doesn't mean they will.